# How can I access from my mobile phone to my XAMPP?

Tags: apache, mobile, xampp, connection

I already had a similar issue some months ago: [Why my access from my mobile to my computer network doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643538/why-my-access-from-my-mobile-to-my-computer-network-doesnt-work)

But this time I cannot get any solution to my problem. I have changed my computer and my network (but it is still a home network) so I think it could be something about configuration but I cannot make it to work.

I already have:

1. `XAMPP` running both `Apache` and `MySQL`.
2. `Apache` is running at port 80.
3. I have allowed a new enter rule on my firewall to allow connections on that port.
4. I have connected my mobile phone and my computer to the same network.
5. I have gone to `CMD` and use the command `ipconfig` to see the IP of my computer.
6. I have put on the browser of my mobile phone the IP that I have got on the step before.

Changes I have tried on `httpd.conf` file:

1. Change on `<Directory />` the directive `Require` from `denied` to `allow`.
2. Before `Listen 80` line I have put `Listen IP of my computer:80`.

On my computer I have `Windows 10`.

What configurations can I prove to solve this? I saw a lot of questions related to the same problem but any of them solved my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can someone explain me why the downvote is?

Comment: Have You tried : Windows, Go to Control Panel -> Firewall, in exceptions "add http and port 80"

Comment: what ipv4 address do you see on `ipconfig`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started)

Run at console/Terminal

```
ngrok http 80
```

You will get something like :

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable

Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0/2.0
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
Forwarding                    https://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80

Connnections                  ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

At the cell phone, open at browser [the link like this that appears at the console](http://92832de0.ngrok.io)

Comment: Thank you! Now I can connect to my `localhost` using the url of `ngrok` but I would like to use `localhost` instead of that url because if not the CSS and the urls of my project does not work. Is it possible?

Comment: As far as I know, android does not know localhost. It know ip, and network. Maybe you want to Try this: http://imrhung.blogspot.co.id/2014/03/connect-real-device-to-localhost-using.html
I do not know how to change localhost will pointing to another ip computer. My friend said it is like DNS, I am not so sure is it possible or not. Never tried it before. So far, I use IP address with no changes at httpd.conf, and NGRok to communicate between android and xampp. Connect to same hotspot/router then get the server ip and access server using the ip. So far is good.

Comment: Maybe you want to try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treb.hosts&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50cmViLmhvc3RzIl0.

It is similar like C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file at windows (maybe) then connect your pc and android using same hotspot, and get your xampp ip, and set / add localhost at android device pointing to your xampp ip.

Comment: Besides ngrok you can also use open source alternative [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/)

Comment: thank you for info, maybe localtunnel is new born app, but maybe that is similar like ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you had this:

   ```
   <Directory />
           AllowOverride none
           Require all denied
   </Directory>
   ```

   You need to change it to:

   ```
   <Directory />
           AllowOverride none
           Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
2. If the mobile phone and the computer are connected within wifi to the network, you should log in into your wifi router and look on the options if you have the option `Wireless Isolation` or `Client Isolation` or `... isolation` enabled, and disable it. This option disables direct connections between wifi clients on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have name based virtual host or ip based virtual host on apache? Just post the first line from apache config?  For testing like this, you can have  . This will make apache listen to all available network interfaces.

In any case, if it's a security problem (allowed, required) you get to see the page in browser, saying access forbidden.

To troubleshoot stuff like this (to determin if it's a firewall problem), it's best to use tcpdump and telnet programs. On server you are listening with tcpdump, on client you issu requests with telnet.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 'port 80'

telnet MYIP 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with XAMPP and eventually realised that it was a firewall issue.

Use your PC's IP, don't worry about the port. Go to your Firewall settings > Inbound rules  > Apache HTTP Server, change to "Allow the connection".

[Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LLYuutc6HI&t=29s) that should give you a step through.

Also I found that I had to change the URL references within my local sites from 'localhost' to my pc's IP.